# How to Find Elliptic IIR Filter Order?

Tags: filters, filter-design, infinite-impulse-response

Can anyone explain to me how to use this equation to find the Order?
Let's say

$$\Omega_p/\Omega_s =0.509$$ and $$e/\delta = 0.00349$$

How can I find the Order? I'm so lost i don't know how to use this equation.

If there is another equation for determining the order to elliptic filters please provide it.

$$N = \frac{K(\Omega_p/\Omega_s)K\left(\sqrt{1-(\epsilon^2/\delta^2)}\right)}{K(\epsilon/\delta)K\left(\sqrt{1-(\Omega_p/\Omega_s)^2}\right)}$$

$$K(x) = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2\theta}}$$

Comment: You'll need a numerical solver to calculate the complete elliptic integral K(x). Octave (Matlab?) has it as `ellipke()`, wxMaxima as `elliptic_kc()`, for example. You'll need to check with the software you're using, or make your own (Gaussian quadrature works very well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we apply your formula, we get:

```
# Python
from math import  ceil
from numpy import sqrt
from scipy.special import ellipk
def K(x):
    return ellipk(x*x)

omega_ratio = 0.509
e_delta_ratio = 0.00349

N = K(omega_ratio)*K(sqrt(1-e_delta_ratio*e_delta_ratio))/(K(e_delta_ratio)*K(sqrt(1-omega_ratio*omega_ratio)))
print(N)   # 3.5420113113759575
print(ceil(N))  # 4
```

```
% matlab
k1 = 0.00349;
k = 0.509;
capk = ellipke([k^2 1-k^2]);
capk1 = ellipke([(k1^2) 1-(k1^2)]);
tmp=(capk(1)*capk1(2)/(capk(2)*capk1(1)))  % 3.5420
order=ceil(tmp)   % 4
```

---

**I don't know where the formula you give comes from, nor do I know whether that formula is correct.**

**I think the algorithm in matlab `ellipord` function may be more reliable.**

Why don't you use matlab `ellipord` function?

By the way, it looks like

```
function [order,wn] = ellipord(wp,ws,rp,rs,opt)
%ELLIPORD Elliptic filter order selection.
%   [N, Wp] = ELLIPORD(Wp, Ws, Rp, Rs) returns the order N of the lowest
%   order digital elliptic filter which has a passband ripple of no more
%   than Rp dB and a stopband attenuation of at least Rs dB. Wp and Ws are
%   the passband and stopband edge frequencies, normalized from 0 to 1
%   (where 1 corresponds to pi radians/sample). For example,
%       Lowpass:    Wp = .1,      Ws = .2
%       Highpass:   Wp = .2,      Ws = .1
%       Bandpass:   Wp = [.2 .7], Ws = [.1 .8]
%       Bandstop:   Wp = [.1 .8], Ws = [.2 .7]
%   ELLIPORD also returns Wp, the elliptic natural frequency to use with
%   ELLIP to achieve the specifications.
%
%   [N, Wp] = ELLIPORD(Wp, Ws, Rp, Rs, 's') does the computation for an
%   analog filter, in which case Wp and Ws are in radians/second.
%
%   NOTE: If Rs is much much greater than Rp, or Wp and Ws are very close,
%   the estimated order can be infinite due to limitations of numerical
%   precision.
%
%   % Example 1:
%   %   For 1000 Hz data, design a lowpass filter with less than 3 dB of
%   %   ripple in the passband defined from 0 to 40 Hz and at least 60 dB
%   %   of ripple in the stopband defined from 150 Hz to the Nyquist
%   %   frequency (500 Hz):
%
%   Wp = 40/500; Ws = 150/500;
%   Rp = 3; Rs = 60;
%   [n,Wp] = ellipord(Wp,Ws,Rp,Rs)      % Gives mimimum order of filter
%   [b,a] = ellip(n,Rp,Rs,Wp);          % Elliptic filter design
%   freqz(b,a,512,1000);                % Plots the frequency response
%   title('n=4 Elliptic Lowpass Filter')
%
%   % Example 2:
%   %   Design a bandpass filter with a passband of 60 Hz to 200 Hz, with
%   %   less than 3 dB of ripple in the passband, and 40 dB attenuation in
%   %   the stopbands that are 50 Hz wide on both sides of the passband.
%
%   Wp = [60 200]/500; Ws = [50 250]/500;
%   Rp = 3; Rs = 40;
%   [n,Wp] = ellipord(Wp,Ws,Rp,Rs)      % Gives mimimum order of filter
%   [b,a] = ellip(n,Rp,Rs,Wp);          % Elliptic filter design
%   freqz(b,a,512,1000)                 % Plots the frequency response
%
%   See also ELLIP, BUTTORD, CHEB1ORD, CHEB2ORD, DESIGNFILT.

%   Author(s): L. Shure, 6-9-88
%              T. Krauss, 11-18-92, updated
%   Copyright 1988-2018 The MathWorks, Inc.

%   Reference(s):
%       [1] Rabiner and Gold, p 241.

narginchk(4,5);  
nargoutchk(0,2); 

if nargin > 4
    opt = convertStringsToChars(opt);
end

% Cast to enforce precision rules
wp = signal.internal.sigcasttofloat(wp,'double','ellipord','Wp','allownumeric');
ws = signal.internal.sigcasttofloat(ws,'double','ellipord','Ws','allownumeric');
rp = signal.internal.sigcasttofloat(rp,'double','ellipord','Rp','allownumeric');
rs = signal.internal.sigcasttofloat(rs,'double','ellipord','Rs','allownumeric');

if nargin == 4
    opt = 'z';
elseif nargin == 5
    if ~strcmp(opt,'z') && ~strcmp(opt,'s')
        error(message('signal:ellipord:InvalidParam'));
    end
end

[msg,msgobj]=freqchk(wp,ws,opt);
if ~isempty(msg), error(msgobj); end

ftype = 2*(length(wp) - 1);
if wp(1) < ws(1)
    ftype = ftype + 1;  % low (1) or reject (3)
else
    ftype = ftype + 2;  % high (2) or pass (4)
end

% first, prewarp frequencies from digital (unit circle) to analog (imag. axis):
if strcmp(opt,'z')  % digital
    WP=tan(pi*wp/2);
    WS=tan(pi*ws/2);
else  % don't have to if analog already
    WP=wp;
    WS=ws;
end

% next, transform to low pass prototype with passband edge of 1 and stopband
% edges determined by the following: (see Rabiner and Gold, p.258)
if ftype == 1   % low
    WA=WS/WP;
    order = findelliporder(WA,rp,rs);
elseif ftype == 2   % high
    WA=WP/WS;
    order = findelliporder(WA,rp,rs);
elseif ftype == 3   % stop
    if strcmp(opt,'s')
        % For analog bandstop, convert back to digital
        wp = 2*atan(wp)/pi;
        ws = 2*atan(ws)/pi;
    end
    Fpass1 = wp(1);
    Fpass2 = wp(2);
    Fstop1 = ws(1);
    Fstop2 = ws(2);
    c = sin(pi*(Fpass1+Fpass2))/(sin(pi*Fpass1)+sin(pi*Fpass2));
    wpa = abs(sin(pi*Fpass2)/(cos(pi*Fpass2)-c));
    ws1 = sin(pi*Fstop1)/(cos(pi*Fstop1)-c);
    ws2 = sin(pi*Fstop2)/(cos(pi*Fstop2)-c);
    wsa = min(abs([ws1,ws2]));
    order = ellipord(wpa,wsa,rp,rs,'s');
elseif ftype == 4   % pass
    WA=(WS.^2 - WP(1)*WP(2))./(WS*(WP(1)-WP(2)));
    order = findelliporder(WA,rp,rs);
end


% natural frequencies are simply the passband edges (WP).
% finally, transform frequencies from analog to digital if necessary:
if strcmp(opt,'z')  % digital
    wn = wp;
else
    wn = WP;
end

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
function order = findelliporder(WA,rp,rs)
% find the minimum order elliptic filter to meet the more demanding spec:
WA = min(abs(WA));
epsilon = sqrt(10^(0.1*rp)-1);
k1 = epsilon/sqrt(10^(0.1*rs)-1);
k = 1/WA;
capk = ellipke([k^2 1-k^2]);
capk1 = ellipke([(k1^2) 1-(k1^2)]);
order = ceil(capk(1)*capk1(2)/(capk(2)*capk1(1)));

% if both warnings are in effect, only print the first one
if (1-k1^2) == 1
    warning(message('signal:ellipord:MustBeFiniteAttn', 'ellipord'))
elseif k^2 == 1
    warning(message('signal:ellipord:MustBeFiniteBandEdges', 'ellipord'))
end
```

---

For science calculation, you can find many APIs in different programming languages.

```
# python
from  scipy.special import ellipk
ellipk(0.509)

# matlab
ellipke(0.509)

# mathematica
EllipticK[0.509]


# All of them output the same value:  1.8617756243745627
# All of them are  Complete elliptic integral of the first kind
```

They all imply the same integral:
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-0.509 \sin ^2(\theta)}} \, \mathrm{d} \theta  \approx 1.86178
$$

```
% however, for matlab there are some weird syntax
[a,b]=ellipke(0.509)     %[a,b]=[1.8618,1.3461]  1st kind complete and 2nd complete
a=ellipke([0.509,0.609])   %a=[1.8618,1.9594]    looks like a map operation on the list with func=1st-kind-complete
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use Python:

```
from math import  ceil
from numpy import sqrt
from scipy.special import ellipk
def K(x):
    return ellipk(x*x)

omega_ratio = 0.509
e_delta_ratio = 0.00349

N = K(omega_ratio)*K(sqrt(1-e_delta_ratio*e_delta_ratio))/(K(e_delta_ratio)*K(sqrt(1-omega_ratio*omega_ratio)))
print(N)   # 3.5420113113759575
print(ceil(N))  # 4
```

which yields

> 3.5420113113759575